# Cannot change spell check language in Ghostwriter

Tags: spell-checking, hunspell

I finally cracked out this issue which was bothering me since some time.

I try to change the spell checking language in `ghostwriter` by setting the french dictionary in `settings->preferences->Spell Check` form.

This setting is ignored and the English dictionary is still used for spell checking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some googling I learned that  `ghostwriter` uses `hunspell`. So I checked that `hunspell-fr` was installed. Doing so, I found that packages from `aspell` and `myspell` where installed to. French dictionary was missing for both of those spelling engines.

As it seems that `hunspell` is the more modern and unicode compliant (according to whot I found with more googling), I decided to uninstall the `aspell` and `myspell` packages.

So to sum-up :

1. check that the hunspell-*xx* package is installed (*xx* is the code for your language)
2. uninstall packages for unnecessary spelling engines
3. set your desired language in ghostwriter